# Master Page form tag runat = server

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, master-pages

i drag a linkbutton into my masterpage and i try to run it , it says i should put a form tag runat = server , after i put it , it says that i can only have 1 form tag , but i check my materpage , don't have any form tag ..

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton1_Click">Logout</asp:LinkButton>
```

My other pages have form tag of runat = server because when i try it , they told me to add it in , What have i done wrong and how should i correct it

My full master page :
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do other pages use master page?

Comment: yes other pages use master page too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Master pages are are also webforms, except that it will combine with content pages to form a single page at runtime. You'll need to put any server control inside `<form runat="server"></form>` . After  you've made this, you don't need to add  tags on other pages which is content page of this master page.

As of now, you can solve your problem by adding a

```
<form runat="server">
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton1_Click">Logout</asp:LinkButton>
</form>
```

Put the ContentPlaceholder control inside the form tag

Remove `<form>` tag from content page

Comment: i did , it says only 1 form allowed

Comment: are u using vs 2013 ?

Comment: @user2376998 you have windows 8 and vs 2010 ? Upgrade it for 2013 express edition

Comment: check out the link (www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx‎)

Comment: the problem is school computers cannot run 2013 , i have to run my projects on school computers

Comment: sorry mate. Just recommended bcuz, it has advanced features.

Comment: yup i know =) i have 2013 too

Comment: mate are u from India ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47112/discussion-between-amit-joki-and-user2376998)